# What is the Angular currency pipe code for Angola country

Tags: angular

I am trying to output the price of products, 
but I would like to know the currencyCode 
for Angola in Angular

I hope there is some code that can 
identify the currency of Angola

This is the variable that receive the value:

```
cur2 = 10.263782;
```

Here i use the curency pipe:

```
{{cur2 | currency:'USD':true:'2.2-4'}}
```

Tis is the output:

```
$10.2638
```

I've tried it this way:

```
{{cur2 | currency:'AOA':true:'2.2-4'}}
```

this too:

```
{{cur2 | currency:'AKZ':true:'2.2-4'}}
{{cur2 | currency:'KZ':true:'2.2-4'}}
```

and it was unsuccessful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Angolan currency is currently only available as a narrow symbol. Therefore the following should do the trick:

```
{{cur2 | currency:'AOA':'symbol-narrow':'2.2-4'}}
```

Comment: I would be very grateful if you provided me with a link for more info

Comment: You can read the official docs [here](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe) but this doesn't explain why AOA is only available in narrow format. I found out by trial and error but it seems to be that the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/7.2.0/packages/common/src/i18n/currencies.ts) only defines narrow formats for some currencies. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer is right. But I try to explain 'why?' not only for you but for other people who will read your question.
Yes for Angola currency in the angular pipe we need use `'symbol-narrow'`. 
[Official documentation of angular](https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe#parameters) explains that for transforming value using currency pipe we need to use format like:

```
{{ value_expression | currency [ : currencyCode [ : display [ : digitsInfo [ : locale ] ] ] ] }}
```

In your question, we are only interested in the parameter `display`.

And documentation gives this description of this parameter for us:

- `code`: Show the code (such as USD).
- `symbol`(default): Show the symbol
  (such as $).
- `symbol-narrow`: Use the narrow symbol for locales that
  have two symbols for their currency. For example, the Canadian dollar
  CAD has the symbol CA$ and the symbol-narrow $. If the locale has no
  narrow symbol, uses the standard symbol for the locale.
- `String`: Use
  the given string value instead of a code or a symbol. For example, an
  empty string will suppress the currency & symbol. Boolean (marked
  deprecated in v5): true for symbol and false for code.

Anngolan currency has two symbols for its designation Kz and kz.

When you use `true` angular understand that thay needs to use the symbol. But you have two symbols for designation this currency in your locale. That's why this parameter did not work for you.